# Why is Mathematica eating a row from QRDecomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to calculate the `QRDecomposition` of the following matrix:

```
a = {{1, 3}, {0, 5}, {2, -8}}

QRDecomposition[a]
```

The answer *Mathematica* gives me is:
- $\mathbf Q$, which is a $2\times3$ matrix
- $\mathbf R$, which is a $2\times2$ matrix

The actual answer that I got using a number of QR decomposition calculators online is a $3\times3$ matrix for $\mathbf Q$ and $3\times2$ matrix for $\mathbf R$. The TA of my class told me that *Mathematica* gives $\mathbf Q^\top$ instead of $\mathbf Q$, so I should just transpose the answer, but clearly $2\times3$ transposed is not $3\times3$. Any ideas?

Comment: `QRDecomposition[]` is computing what is called a "thin" or "economy" QR, where the orthonormal factor inherits the dimensions of the rectangular matrix. There are relations with this and "full QR" that you can use, however. Search around.

Answer (score 18):

As I have previously noted, `QRDecomposition[]` is by default set to return the so-called "thin QR" or "economy QR" decomposition; this is often the form desired in applications, since the triangular factor does not have the unneeded zero rows. MATLAB's [`qr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html), by contrast, returns the full QR decomposition by default, and the economy QR through an option setting.

Here, then, is a general routine for producing the full QR decomposition, adapted from [this old linear algebra tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixComputations.html#658148687). I have elected to also extend this routine to the case where QR *with column pivoting* is wanted (sometimes a must in certain least squares applications):

```
Options[FullQRDecomposition] = Options[QRDecomposition];
FullQRDecomposition[mat_?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[FullQRDecomposition]] := 
      Module[{prec = Precision[mat], dec},  
             dec = QRDecomposition[mat, Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~
                                   Options[FullQRDecomposition],
                                   Options[QRDecomposition]]];
             dec = MapAt[PadRight[#, Dimensions[mat], N[0, {prec, prec}]] &,
                         dec, 2];
             dec = MapAt[Orthogonalize[Join[#, NullSpace[#]]] &, dec, 1];
             dec]
```

Using the OP's example:

```
a = {{1., 3.}, {0., 5.}, {2., -8.}};

{qq, rr} = FullQRDecomposition[a];
Transpose[qq].rr - a // Chop
   {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}

{qq, rr, piv} = FullQRDecomposition[a, Pivoting -> True];
Transpose[qq].rr - a.piv // Chop
   {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Comment: P.S. As a point of contrast, `SingularValueDecomposition[]` returns the "full SVD" by default (although one can use the second argument to yield the "thin SVD") in the same manner as MATLAB's `svd()`.

Comment: Your `qq` does not appear to be a unitary matrix; i.e., the third row of `qq`, although orthogonal to the other two rows, is not normalized.  Thus, `Transpose[qq].qq` does not yield the identity matrix.  This is, of course, easy to fix.

Comment: Huh… what results are you getting? I did test `qq` for orthogonality with and without pivoting, and I obtain something that looks like the identity matrix after a `Chop[]`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. The discrepancy is due to `NullSpace[]` using SVD in the inexact case, but Gaussian elimination otherwise. Let me fix that…

Answer (score 11):

The relationship between `Q` and `R` as computed by `QRDecomposition` and the "full QR" results (as described by J. M.} can be found in, for instance, [Wikipedia](http://QRDecomposition).  The following illustrates how to go from the *Mathematica* to the Wikipedia formulation.  With `a` as defined in the question,

```
{q, r} = QRDecomposition[a]
(* {{{1/Sqrt[5], 0, 2/Sqrt[5]}, 
     {28/Sqrt[1605], 5 Sqrt[5/321], -(14/Sqrt[1605])}}, 
    {{Sqrt[5], -(13/Sqrt[5])}, {0, Sqrt[321/5]}}} *)
```

To obtain the `R` that you are seeking, add a third row of zeroes.

```
rr = Join[r, {{0, 0}}]
(* {{Sqrt[5], -(13/Sqrt[5])}, {0, Sqrt[321/5]}, {0, 0}} *)
```

To obtain the full `Q`, one must determine a third row, orthonormal to the first two, and append it.

```
Solve[{q.{q1, q2, q3} == 0, q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 == 1}, {q1, q2, q3}][[1]];
qq = Join[q, {{q1, q2, q3}}]/.%
(* {{1/Sqrt[5], 0, 2/Sqrt[5]}, 
    {28/Sqrt[1605], 5 Sqrt[5/321], -(14/Sqrt[1605])}, 
    {-(10/Sqrt[321]), 14/Sqrt[321], 5/Sqrt[321]}} *)
```

To prove that the decomposition is correct, recover `a`

```
Transpose[qq].rr
(* {{1, 3}, {0, 5}, {2, -8}} *)
```